# R lm model creation with data containing NA

Tags: r, na, lm

If my data frame is 100 rows with 5 columns,
and a third of the rows have say, 2 NA values (from the input data) how are those rows handled?

I read lm {stats} but still am unsure what happens settings na.action to true or false.

Does na.action = TRUE drop the entire row, or just drop the NA variables for that row as the model is created? (using the other columns)

Thank you

Comment: Relevant - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/how-does-r-handle-missing-values-in-lm "*na.omit and na.exclude both do casewise deletion*"

Comment: As I have thought more deeply about this, my original intent would now be solved by building something that could be described as a massively recursive meta-model. Thus given data with randomly placed NA values, a less robust but best appropriate sub-model could still include the data to generate an output.  Thus, in reality, best solved by more models.

Comment: You may be interested in multiple imputation approaches.

Answer (score 1):

ben_says

Per `lm` documentation `na.action` by defalut will do whatever `options("na.action")` returns.

In my case that is `na.omit` and this means that rows with NA will be removed.

As I understanding there are 4 options that `na.action` can be set to:

```
na.fail 
na.omit
na.exclude
na.pass
```